# Why does my code gives Name Attribute Error in ANGULAR 5?

Tags: angular

I have a question about formcontrol in Angular 5. Why does my code gives Name Attribute  Error  in ANGULAR 5 ? I do not understand where error is. I am facing an error like `Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`. Could you help me at this issue ? I do not insert data to my api service althought i add import essential library to app.module.ts in my project.

My example json format

```
{
    "id": "",
    "name": "",
    "address": "",
    "contactName": "",
    "contactSurname": "",
    "contactPhone": "",
    "secondContactPhone":"",
    "city": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asd"
    },
    "town": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "asd",
        "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "asd"              
        }
    }
}
```

My html page

```
  <table style="width:500px;">
      <tr><td>New city</td>
        <td>
          <select >
            <option  *ngFor="let sec of bank" [(ngModel)]="city" [name]="name">{{sec?.city?.name}} </option><!--Deneme city -->
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>New city</td>
        <td>
          <select >
            <option  *ngFor="let sec of bank" [(ngModel)]="town">{{sec?.town?.name}}</option><!--Deneme town -->
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"  ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New address:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="address" [(ngModel)]="address"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New contactName:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="contactName" [(ngModel)]="contactName"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New contactSurname:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="contactSurname" [(ngModel)]="contactSurname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New contactPhone:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="contactPhone" [(ngModel)]="contactPhone"  ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New secondContactPhone:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="secondContactPhone" [(ngModel)]="secondContactPhone"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button (click)="Create();">add</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This is a form issue : You didn't declare a `name` variable, so `[(ngModel)]="name"` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

not a full answer but I checked your json format with this online [editor](http://jsoneditoronline.org/) and corrected it:

```
{
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "address": "",
        "contactName": "",
        "contactSurname": "",
        "contactPhone": "",
"secondContactPhone":"",
        "city": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "asd"

        },
        "town": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "asd",
            "city": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "asd"                
            }
        }
}
```